# SimplePie: Fetch result starting from the first entries of the feed

Tags: php, foreach, rss, feed, simplepie

I have a function which extracts data from an rss feed though simplepie. I have a `foreach ( $rss_items as $item )` and a list of items. Every `<li>` has its `$item->get_title();` and `$item->get_permalink();`. Then I have `$item->get_content();`, which I call once outsite the foreach. The result is the first entry of the feed starting from the bottom. How can I have `$item->get_content();` to fetch the first entry of the feed starting from the top?

Answer (score 2):

if you call `$item->get_content()` after the `foreach`, it will always contain the last post, since `$item` is overwritten in each iteration.

To keep the content of the first post:

```
$firstContent = null;
$firstIsSet = false;
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) {
    if (!$firstIsSet) {
        $firstContent = $item->get_content();
        $firstIsSet = true;
    }
    ...
}

echo $firstContent;
```

Now, the `$firstContent` will contain the content of the first post.

Comment: You could also use the `break` command to break out of the loop if the first item is all you want to get.